# Protect ArrayList from write access

Tags: java

Consider the following class:

```
public class Cars extends Observable{

    private ArrayList<String> carList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void addToCarList(String car){
        // ...
        hasChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public void removeFromCarList(String car){
        // ...
        hasChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCarList() {
        return carList;
    }    
}
```

As you can see, every time the carList is changed, I want to notify the `Observers`. 
If someone does `getCarList().add(...);`, this is circumvented.

How can I give read access to the `carList` (for iterating over it etc.) but prevent write access to it except for the special methods  `addToCarList` and `removeFromCarList`?

I thought about this:

```
public ArrayList<String> getCarList() {
    return (ArrayList<String>)carList.clone();
}
```

but someone using my class would, when adding something to the clone of `carList`, not be informed that that's not the way it's meant to be done.

Comment: Although to me, extending from ArrayList<T>, overriding the add and remove functions to notify the observers, and making Observable an interface would seem like a simpler way of doing things.

Comment: Instead of providing method getCarList(), why not provide getCarAtIndex() and getCarCount()

Comment: @Will I like that one. You can even implement an iterator! Might make for a good answer actually.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can return an unmodifiable view of it, changing the return type to `List<String>` instead of `ArrayList<String>`:

```
public List<String> getCars() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(carList);
}
```

Note that as [`Collections.unmodifiableList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-) *does* only provide a view, the caller will still see any other changes that are made via `addToCarList` and `removeFromCarList` (which I'd rename to `addCar` and `removeCar`, probably). Is that what you want?

Any mutating operations on the returned view will result in an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: This is correct. Just make sure to make your carList private (even though it already is). If not, users can still be tempted to access the variable that way. See here: http://www.javacreed.com/modifying-an-unmodifiable-list/

Comment: @dberm22: It's already private in the question... I'm not sure why you've brought that up.

Comment: I know...I was just adding so that future readers don't see your correct example and then ruin it by overlooking the public variable. It was just a warning to future viewers, not a note to the OP.

Answer (score 13):

First, always avoid using concrete class at the left side of assignment and as a return value of method. So, fix your class as

```
public class Cars extends Observable{

    private List<String> carList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ........................

   public List<String> getCarList() {
        return carList;
   }
}
```

Now you can use `Collections.unmodifiableList()` to make you list read-only:

```
   public List<String> getCarList() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(carList);
   }
```

BTW, if you do not really have to return `List` you can probably return `Collection` or even `Iterable`. This will make increase the encapsulation level of your code and make future modifications easier.

Answer (score 9):

Jon Skeet's answer is excellent (as always) but the one thing it doesn't touch on is concurrency issues.

Returning an unmodifiable collection will still leave you with issues if multiple threads are accessing this object at the same time. For example if one thread is iterating over the list of cars and then at the same time another thread adds a new card.

You will still need to synchronize access to that list somehow, and this is one reason why you might consider returning a `clone()` of the list as well as or instead of just wrapping it in the `unmodifiableList` wrapper. You would still need to synchronize around the `clone()` but once the clone is completed and the list returned to the querying code it no longer needs to be synchronized.

Comment: Good point. Jon Skeet actually mentioned that `Collection.unmodifiable()` returns a view but it is not clear from his answer what it can cause in multithreaded environment.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could probably make your Object implement the Collection-Interface, if it is in fact an ObservableList. It is a List and it should be Observable - so it should implement both interfaces.

You could even Extend List<..> because you just want to add extra functionality (observers) to the current functionality and your List can be used everywhere where a normal List could be used...

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt/21699942

Comment: Hmm... I see a completely different usecase here. It looks like in fact he wants to implement an ObservableCollection, which is observable and IS a Collection. i.e. should implement the Collection interface. Then he could do the same as the ReadOnlyList class and just throw exceptions on unsupported actions and notify listeners and so on...

Comment: For a generic `ObservableCollection` if that is what he is making that would make sense, it really depends on what the class in question is doing but that's a valid point. Removed the downvote :)

Comment: @TimB In C#, a List is a concrete class, but in Java List is an interface, so I don't think that answer is relevant here.

Comment: @DavidConrad It really depends on whether what he is writing is a generic `ObservableList` or is another class that contains an `ObservableList`. Having said that the second case may well be best handled by creating the `ObservableList` anyway and then using that internally so actually I'm sort of changing my mind here.

Answer (score 0):

use Collections.unmodifiableList(list) as it provides a new List object which cannot be modified , it would throw an UnsupportedOperationException while trying to update/add/delete objects list.